# Laravel relationships, Many to Many or Has Many Through?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm building a web app using Laravel 8 and one thing I tend to struggle with is the complex relationships and accessing the data. I've started reading on `hasManyThrough` relationships but I'm not convinced that's the correct way to do it for my scenario.

The app is used by travelling salesmen to check in to a location when they arrive safely.

I have three main tables:

- `Locations` (where they are visiting),
- `Checkins` (where their check in data is stored, e.g. time),
- `Users`

This is where it gets a little complex and where I find myself not being able to see the wood for the trees...

- Locations have many users, users have many locations. Many-to-many pivot table created.
- Locations have many check ins, check ins have many locations. Many-to-many pivot table created.
- Check ins have many users, users have many check ins. Many-to-many pivot table created.

As such they're all created using a `belongsToMany` relationship.

Now what I'd like to do is access the `user` of the `check in` so I can call something similar to on my `show.blade.php`:

```
<tbody>
 @foreach($location->checkins as $checkin)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $checkin->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $checkin->users()->name }}</td> // I'd like to get the users name
   <td>{{ $checkin->longitude }}</td>
   <td>{{ $checkin->latitude }}</td>
   <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($checkin->created_at)->format('jS F Y') }}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Is a `hasManyThrough` relationship the only way I can achieve this? Or should I get a bit more creative with my controller and bring users through on their own collection?

My current `Location` controller looks like this:

```
public function show(Location $location)
 {
  $page_title = "Locations";
  $page_description = "Event locations.";

  return view('pages.admin.locations.show', compact('page_title', 'page_description'))
    ->with('location' => $location);
 }
```

Any direction or best practice advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "Check ins have many users", you seem to want the singular user for a check-in, but currently that would result in many users. It sounds like users check-in in a many to one relationship

Also `$checkin->created_at` will be by default a carbon object, so you can just go `$checkin->created_at->format('jS F Y')`

Also don't mix using `compact` and `with`, stay consistent and use only 1 as they achieve the same thing

Also `$checkin->users()->name` won't work, if you use the brackets on syntax is only returns a query builder instance, which you would need to call get on like `$checkin->users()->get()`, or you could use `$checkin->users` which will fetch them anyway. You may want to look into using `with('relation')` on query builder instances to stop N+1 queries if you want to dive a little deeper. Lastly `$checkin->users()->get()->name` also won't work as your user relation is many to many which returns a collection, which again points to you should have a belongsTo relationship called `user` without a pivot table

Comment: Thanks Ben, great answer. So I went to bed, slept on it to clear my head and came back this morning, realising that I'd just got down a rabbit hole and complicated things more than I needed to. I have changed to one-to-many relationships between check ins, users and locations and it's now working a charm. Thanks again!